# SharePoint 2013 api Angular table (Works On Edit mode)

Tags: sharepoint

i try to show a table from angular
i use sharepoint api with angular get request in webpart (content edit)
i see table data only if i edit webpart
screenshots(Regular mode)

screenshots(edit mode)
[regular mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWJ4E.jpg)

[edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADBOA.jpg)

whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The code below for your reference.

```
<h1>WelCome To Angular JS Sharepoint 2013 REST API !!</h1>
<div id="mytest" ng-app="SharePointAngApp" class="row">
    <div ng-controller="spCustomerController" class="span10">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
                <td>{{customer.ID}}</td>
                <td>{{customer.Title}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
#mytest table,#mytest td, #mytest th {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#mytest th {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myAngApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp', []);
myAngApp.controller('spCustomerController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListA')/items?$select=ID,Title",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.customers = data.d.results;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]